Error Processing PayPal Payment in Next.js: "Failed to create order"
I'm having an issue while trying to integrate PayPal payments in my Next.js application. Specifically, I'm receiving the following error:
app-index.js:32 Error processing PayPal payment: Error: Failed to create order
    at handleApprove (index.tsx:75:15)

I have a backend folder called endpoints that handles the PayPal order creation. Inside the folder I have two specific files that focus on PayPal payment the first one is a create-payment-intent.ts:
// eslint-disable-next-line simple-import-sort/imports
import type { PayloadHandler } from "payload/config";
import axios from "axios";
import type { CartItems } from "../payload-types";

const PAYPAL_API_BASE = "https://sandbox.paypal.com";

const getPayPalAccessToken = async (): Promise<string> => {
  const clientId = process.env.PAYPAL_CLIENT_ID || "";
  const clientSecret = process.env.PAYPAL_CLIENT_SECRET || "";
  const auth = Buffer.from(`${clientId}:${clientSecret}`).toString("base64");
  const response = await axios.post(
    `${PAYPAL_API_BASE}/v1/oauth2/token`,
    "grant_type=client_credentials",
    {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Basic ${auth}`,
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
      },
    }
  );
  return response.data.access_token;
};

export const createPayPalOrder: PayloadHandler = async (
  req,
  res
): Promise<void> => {
  const { user, payload } = req;
  if (!user) {
    res.status(401).send("Unauthorized");
    return;
  }

  const fullUser = await payload.findByID({
    collection: "users",
    id: user?.id,
  });
  if (!fullUser) {
    res.status(404).json({ error: "User not found" });
    return;
  }

  try {
    let total = 0;
    const hasItems = fullUser?.cart?.items?.length > 0;
    if (!hasItems) {
      throw new Error("No items in cart");
    }

    await Promise.all(
      fullUser?.cart?.items?.map(async (item: CartItems[0]): Promise<null> => {
        const { product, quantity } = item;
        if (!quantity) {
          return null;
        }
        if (typeof product === "string" || !product?.price) {
          throw new Error("No Product Price");
        }
        total += product.price * quantity;
        return null;
      })
    );

    if (total === 0) {
      throw new Error(
        "There is nothing to pay for, add some items to your cart and try again."
      );
    }

    const accessToken = await getPayPalAccessToken();
    const orderResponse = await axios.post(
      `${PAYPAL_API_BASE}/v2/checkout/orders`,
      {
        intent: "CAPTURE",
        purchase_units: [
          {
            amount: {
              currency_code: "USD",
              value: (total / 100).toFixed(2),
            },
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
      }
    );

    res.send({ orderID: orderResponse.data.id });
  } catch (error: unknown) {
    const message = error instanceof Error ? error.message : "Unknown error";
    payload.logger.error(message);
    res.json({ error: message });
  }
};

The second file is called capture-paypal-order.ts:
// eslint-disable-next-line simple-import-sort/imports
import type { PayloadHandler } from "payload/config";
import axios from "axios";

const PAYPAL_API_BASE = "https://sandbox.paypal.com";

const getPayPalAccessToken = async (): Promise<string> => {
  const clientId = process.env.PAYPAL_CLIENT_ID || "";
  const clientSecret = process.env.PAYPAL_CLIENT_SECRET || "";
  const auth = Buffer.from(`${clientId}:${clientSecret}`).toString("base64");
  const response = await axios.post(
    `${PAYPAL_API_BASE}/v1/oauth2/token`,
    "grant_type=client_credentials",
    {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Basic ${auth}`,
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
      },
    }
  );
  return response.data.access_token;
};

export const capturePayPalOrder: PayloadHandler = async (
  req,
  res
): Promise<void> => {
  const { user } = req;
  if (!user) {
    res.status(401).send("Unauthorized");
    return;
  }

  const { orderID } = req.body;
  if (!orderID) {
    res.status(400).json({ error: "Order ID is required" });
    return;
  }

  try {
    const accessToken = await getPayPalAccessToken();
    const captureResponse = await axios.post(
      `${PAYPAL_API_BASE}/v2/checkout/orders/${orderID}/capture`,
      {},
      {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
      }
    );

    res.send({
      status: captureResponse.data.status,
      captureID: captureResponse.data.id,
    });
  } catch (error: unknown) {
    const message = error instanceof Error ? error.message : "Unknown error";
    res.json({ error: message });
  }
};

I am trying to test if I can successfully make online purchases using the sandbox accounts. However, when I log in using the PayPal business account, I encounter the error "I must be a seller to make a purchase." I created a seller account, but I still used the API keys from the business account since I cannot create an app(which gives me api keys) with the seller account.
I have consoled logged and verified that my order IDs are being captured correctly:
Order Data after Capture: 
Object
captureID: "7VU536339L123614E"
status: "COMPLETED"

Also here is the PayPal button code in my components folder:
"use client";
// eslint-disable-next-line simple-import-sort/imports
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { PayPalButtons, PayPalScriptProvider } from "@paypal/react-paypal-js";
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";
import { useCart } from "../../_providers/Cart";

const PayPalButton: React.FC = () => {
  const router = useRouter();
  const { cart, cartTotal, clearCart } = useCart();
  const [paypalOrderID, setPaypalOrderID] = useState<string | null>(null);
  const [error, setError] = useState<string | null>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const createPayPalOrder = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await fetch(
          `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SERVER_URL}/api/create-payment-intent`,
          {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
              "Content-Type": "application/json",
            },
            credentials: "include",
            body: JSON.stringify({ cartTotal: cartTotal.raw }),
          }
        );

        if (!response.ok) {
          throw new Error(`HTTP error! status: ${response.status}`);
        }

        const data = await response.json();
        console.log("PayPal Order Creation Response:", data);
        setPaypalOrderID(data.orderID);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Failed to create PayPal order:", error);
        setError("Failed to create PayPal order. Please try again.");
      }
    };

    createPayPalOrder();
  }, [cartTotal]);

  const handleApprove = async (data: { orderID: string }) => {
    try {
      console.log("Handling PayPal Approval for Order ID:", data.orderID);
      const response = await fetch(
        `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SERVER_URL}/api/capture-paypal-order`,
        {
          method: "POST",
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
          },
          credentials: "include",
          body: JSON.stringify({
            orderID: data.orderID,
            cartItems: cart?.items,
            cartTotal: cartTotal.raw,
          }),
        }
      );

      if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error(`HTTP error! status: ${response.status}`);
      }

      const orderData = await response.json();
      console.log("Order Data after Capture:", orderData);

      if (orderData.id) {
        clearCart();
        router.push(`/order-confirmation?order_id=${orderData.id}`);
      } else {
        throw new Error("Failed to create order");
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error processing PayPal payment:", error);
      setError("Error processing payment. Please try again.");
    }
  };

  if (error) {
    return <div>Error: {error}</div>;
  }

  if (!paypalOrderID) {
    return <div>Loading PayPal...</div>;
  }

  return (
    <PayPalScriptProvider
      options={{ clientId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_PAYPAL_CLIENT_ID }}
    >
      <PayPalButtons
        createOrder={() => Promise.resolve(paypalOrderID)}
        onApprove={(data) => handleApprove(data)}
        onError={(err) => {
          console.error("PayPal Error:", err);
          setError("PayPal encountered an error. Please try again.");
        }}
      />
    </PayPalScriptProvider>
  );
};

export default PayPalButton;

I have been struggling with these issue for 2 days doing everything looking back and front and don't know what is wrong. I even tried to google search for the solution but nothing so far has helped me. Any help would be greatly appreciated!
